# d3 duplicate svg's on update data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Whenever my graph is populated with new data a new svg element is generated. The update pattern sort of works as new circles are added in the newly generated svg, and also removed circles are being removed. But i can't figure out why it keeps generating a new svg element on a data change.

```
        var margin = 20,
            width = 960,
            height = 400;


        var svg = d3.select('#authorities').append('svg')
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', height);

        function update(data) {
            // calculate minimum/maximum for axis
            var y_extent = d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.NumberOfAuthorities}) + 1;
            var x_extent = d3.min(data, function(d){ return d.ReimbursementTimeline}) + 20;

            // accept values between min and max extent
            var x_scale = d3.scale.linear()
                .range([margin, width-margin])
                .domain([0, x_extent]);

            var y_scale = d3.scale.linear()
                .range([height-margin, margin])
                .domain([0, y_extent]);

            var circle = svg.selectAll('circle')
                .data(data, function(d) { return d.Country; });

            circle
                .enter()
                    .append('circle')
                        .attr('cy', function(d){return y_scale(d.NumberOfAuthorities)})
                        .attr('cx', function(d){return x_scale(d.ReimbursementTimeline)})
                        .attr('data-country', function(d){return d.Country})
                        .attr('r', function(d){ return (d.NumberOfAuthorities * d.ReimbursementTimeline)/10});

            circle.exit().remove();
        }

        update(data);
```

Comment: I can't see anything in your code which would lead to this happening. Could you try changing your svg to `svg=d3.select('#authorities').selectAll('svg.svgCanvas').data([0]).enter().append('svg').attr('class', 'svgCanvas').attr('width', width).attr('height', height);` Essentially what this would do is make sure that your svg creation line can't create more than one svg. If the problem persists, I think you'll have to look elsewhere for a solution.

Comment: Yes, as @JSBob says nothing in the code snippet you posted above would create a duplicate `svg` element.  Can you put together a reproducible example?